# In a Camunda embedded form, can a select have the multiple attribute?

Tags: camunda

Within a user task, the embedded form markup is

```
  ...
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="customer">Customer</label>
    <select class="form-control"
           cam-variable-name="customerId"
           cam-variable-type="String"
           cam-choices="customerList"
           name="customer" />
  </div>
  ...
```

The select is populated with a `java.util.Map` of customer-id and customer-name and the associated Camunda process variable is populated with the customer-id as a single `String` after form submission.

If the select has the

```
multiple="multiple"
```

attribute set, does this work?

Reading the Camunda manual, for selects, the only variable types allows are String, Integer, Long and Short
ie an array or list type is not supported.

How are the multiple selections accessed from the single `String`?

Answer (score 1):

Using Camunda 7.10, the `multiple` attribute is supported. Adding this attribute to the embedded form markup

```
...
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="customer">Customer</label>
    <select class="form-control"
           cam-variable-name="customerId"
           cam-variable-type="String"
           cam-choices="customerList"
           name="customer"
           multiple="multiple" />
</div>
...
```

On form submit, the variable `customerId` is populated with a square-bracket de-limited, comma-separated-value list of values of the form

```
[10,11,12]
```

This can be seen in the process variable display.

In the form processing code, typically a user-task listener, the concatenated `String` must then be parsed to extract the selected values.